# Auto-cleaning workspace that fails with corrupted git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

On our Jenkins, sometimes because of some bitbucket.org issues I assume, the git repositories goes into a bad state on the slave machines. Further the builds starts to fail and never recovers. We find failed builds with several different git checkout errors.

The only action that could recover it was to manually perform a cleanup work space before build starts option in Jenkins job. But cannot keep the option turned on, to save the time and traffic.

Recently found another much better option of cleaning up workspace from a Post Build Action, that has an additional benefit of checking for the build status. So now configured it to be executed only when the build fails.

But I wonder if we can have even fine grained control. i.e. perform cleanup of local workspace/repo only when there is a real git error. I don't have to clean workspace for a compilation error, for example. E.g. option could be to check "git fsck" and perform cleanup only if it has a non-zero return code.

Has anyone tried a working solution for this?

Comment: generally speaking there is no harm in cleaning the workspace as a post action. If you want to only do it when there is a git error, your proposed solution sounds pretty good to me.

Comment: Yes, the solution works good for me too. But not very optimal. The problem is that it cannot differentiate between repository related errors and other common errors like compilation errors...etc.

Comment: for us it works pretty well to wipe the workspace after every run (even successful ones) and start every job with a clean slate. But like I said, the approach you laid out in the question seems like a good solution for this problem

Comment: Totally in agreement with you. But the problem could be our repository huge size, where the repository pull takes several minutes (5+ minutes) for a fresh clone. So cleaning up repository each time is not a good option for us. Also there are dashboards that monitor the branch and build status that refreshes every 5 minutes. Anyway, I will do a little more research and see if I can have an even better solution.